# How to get notification.alertBody in my app from a remote push notification?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I just followed this tutorial [Push notification](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) and I successfully implemented the push notification for my iPhone app. Im able to get now the notification Details. However, I wanted to put the notification alertBody on a Label provided for notification alertBody.

I have a code in displaying the notification alertBody from a local Notification. But I know it is different from a push notification because it is used only for local notification.

on my AppDelagate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",notif);
NSString *_stringFromNotification = notif.alertBody;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Notification" object:_stringFromNotification];
}
```

on my ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

 [super viewDidLoad];     

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"Notification" object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note)
NSString *_string = note.object;
//Do something with the string--------
}];

}
```

It works perfectly on Local Notification but for push notification, It doesn't work. How to Implement this? Need your help please. I need to put the notification alert body at the Label or String.

Answer (score 3):

```
first of all register for remote notifications in AppDelegate.m in method,

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//Invoke APNS.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}

And then use following delegate method to recieve remote notification:
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSLog(@"Received =%@",userInfo);////userInfo will contain all the details of notification like alert body.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remote notifications run outside the sandbox the app is running in, so you can't capture the notification in the same way as local notifications, i.e. `application:didReceiveLocalNotification`. However, if the app is launched via the remote notification, you can capture the notification via the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if (notification) {
        // do something with the notification.alertBody
    } else {
        // from the springboard
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application is already running when it receives a remote notification, your application delegate's [`– application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidReceiveRemoteNotification%3a) method will be called; if the application is not currently running and is launched in response to the notification, the remote notification info will be put into the `launchOptions` dictionary in your [`– application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidFinishLaunchingWithOptions%3a) method.

Answer (score 0):

The method which you are implementing is for local notification only. If you want to handle push notification then you have to use method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification: (NSDictionary*)userInfo{
NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);

}
```

for the same. This method will be called if the app is on background only. If the app is not in background then you can fetch data in the following manner

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
UILocalNotification *notificationData = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

if(!notificationData){
    NSLog(@"App launched by tapping on app icon");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Notification data -> %@",notificationData);
}
}
```